# Python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I can't locate this element.. I'm trying to un-check the history box and dl box (they're checked by default)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


chrome_path = r"C:\Users\Skid\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("chrome://settings/clearBrowserData")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id=delete-browsing-history-checkbox"]""") #unchecks history
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="delete-download-history-checkbox"]""") #unchecks dl history
```

This is the page source that someone wanted me to update.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="uber" class="" i18n-values="dir:textdirection;lang:language" dir="ltr" lang="en" i18n-processed=""><head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title i18n-content="pageTitle">Settings - Clear browsing data</title>
<link id="favicon" rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="chrome://theme/IDR_SETTINGS_FAVICON" />
<link id="favicon2x" rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="chrome://theme/IDR_SETTINGS_FAVICON@2x" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="chrome://resources/css/chrome_shared.css" />
<style>/* Copyright (c) 2012 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
 * Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
 * found in the LICENSE file. */

body {
  /* http://crbug.com/129406 --- horizontal scrollbars flicker when changing
   * sections. */
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#navigation {
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  /* This is a hack to prevent the navigation bar from occluding pointer events
   * from the bottom scroll bar (which shows when one needs to horizontally
   * scroll). Corresponding padding-top to offset this is in uber_frame.css */
  margin-top: -20px;
  position: absolute;
  /* This value is different from the left value to compensate for the scroll
   * bar (which is always on and to the right) in RTL. */
  right: 15px;
  width: 155px;
  z-index: 3;
}

#navigation.background {
  z-index: 1;
}

#navigation.changing-content {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 100ms, width 100ms;
}

.iframe-container {
  -webkit-margin-start: -20px;
  -webkit-transition: margin 100ms, opacity 100ms;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.iframe-container.selected {
  -webkit-margin-start: 0;
  -webkit-transition: margin 200ms, opacity 200ms;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 100ms;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

.iframe-container.expanded {
  left: 0;
}

iframe {
  border: none;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>

<script src="chrome://resources/js/cr.js"></script>
<script src="chrome://resources/js/cr/ui/focus_manager.js"></script>
<script src="chrome://resources/js/load_time_data.js"></script>
<script src="chrome://resources/js/util.js"></script>

<script src="chrome://chrome/uber.js"></script>
<script src="chrome://chrome/uber_utils.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="navigation" data-width="155" class="changing-content background" style="transform: translateX(0px);"><iframe src="chrome://uber-frame/" name="chrome" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"></iframe></div>

<div class="iframe-container" i18n-values="id:historyHost; data-url:historyFrameURL;" data-favicon="IDR_HISTORY_FAVICON" id="history" data-url="chrome://history-frame/" hidden="" aria-hidden="true"></div>
<div class="iframe-container" i18n-values="id:extensionsHost; data-url:extensionsFrameURL;" data-favicon="IDR_EXTENSIONS_FAVICON" id="extensions" data-url="chrome://extensions-frame/" hidden="" aria-hidden="true"></div>
<div class="iframe-container selected" i18n-values="id:settingsHost; data-url:settingsFrameURL;" data-favicon="IDR_SETTINGS_FAVICON" id="settings" data-url="chrome://settings-frame/" aria-hidden="false" data-title="Settings - Clear browsing data"><iframe name="settings" role="presentation" src="chrome://settings-frame/clearBrowserData" data-ready="true"></iframe></div>
<div class="iframe-container" i18n-values="id:helpHost; data-url:helpFrameURL;" data-favicon="IDR_PRODUCT_LOGO_16" id="help" data-url="chrome://help-frame/" hidden="" aria-hidden="true"></div>

<script src="chrome://chrome/strings.js"></script>
<script src="chrome://resources/js/i18n_template.js"></script>



</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`driver.find_element_by_xpath` is just looking for the checkbox and returning it as `WebElement`. You want to click on it to unchecked it

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="delete-browsing-history-checkbox"]""").click()
```

Also, you forgot apostrophes in the first xpath after `@id=`. It should be like in the example above.

> Edit

You can try locating the checkbox by id

```
 driver.find_element_by_id("delete-browsing-history-checkbox").click()
```

> Edit 2

The checkbox are inside `iframe`. You need to switch to it first

```
driver.switch_to.frame("settings") # switch to the iframe by name attribute
# driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name("settings")) # should also work
driver.find_element_by_id("delete-browsing-history-checkbox").click()
driver.switch_to.default_content() # switch back to main window
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that. I shoulda told you that.. here's the error

selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[@id=delete-browsing-history-checkbox"] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[@id=delete-browsing-history-checkbox"]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: @nobodyskiddy see the edit to my question, I already answered on that :)

Comment: I still get an error :(
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="delete-browsing-history-checkbox"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=48.0.2564.109)

Comment: @nobodyskiddy I added another solution.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a `find_element_by...` all you get is the element. You also need to have a `.click()` on that element.

Either:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id=delete-browsing-history-checkbox"]""")
elem.click()
```

or:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id=delete-browsing-history-checkbox"]""").click()
```

Btw, you could just use `find_element_by_id("delete-browsing-history-checkbox")` in your case.

<strike>Also, I don't think selenium works on non-web pages. So chrome settings and Firefox's `about:config` pages (for example) don't work with selenium.</strike>

Answer (score 1):

Can you add to your question what you get as body from selenium?

```
 driver.get("chrome://settings/clearBrowserData")
 driver.page_source
```

If I check the source code in Google Chrome of this page I get:

`view-source:chrome://chrome/settings/clearBrowserData`

```
<body>

<div id="navigation"><iframe src="chrome://uber-frame/" name="chrome" role="presentation"></iframe></div>

<div class="iframe-container"
    i18n-values="id:historyHost; data-url:historyFrameURL;"
    data-favicon="IDR_HISTORY_FAVICON"></div>
<div class="iframe-container"
    i18n-values="id:extensionsHost; data-url:extensionsFrameURL;"
    data-favicon="IDR_EXTENSIONS_FAVICON"></div>
<div class="iframe-container"
    i18n-values="id:settingsHost; data-url:settingsFrameURL;"
    data-favicon="IDR_SETTINGS_FAVICON"></div>
<div class="iframe-container"
    i18n-values="id:helpHost; data-url:helpFrameURL;"
    data-favicon="IDR_PRODUCT_LOGO_16"></div>

<script src="chrome://chrome/strings.js"></script>
<script src="chrome://resources/js/i18n_template.js"></script>

</body>
```

It might be necessary to find another way to do it, if your driver cannot see this node.

**Edit**

In the source code you posted as `page_source` returned from selenium, there isn't the node you are trying to find.